# Pandas - Check if Numbers in Column are in row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-manipulation

I have a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
user_id product_id order_number
1       1          1
1       1          2
1       1          3
1       2          1
1       2          5
2       1          1
2       1          3
2       1          4
2       1          5
3       1          1
3       1          2
3       1          6
```

I wanted to query this df for the longest streak (none order_number is skipped) and last streak (since last order_number).

The ideal result is as follows:

```
user_id product_id longest_streak last_streak
1       1          3              3
1       2          0              0
2       1          3              3
3       1          2              0
```

I'd appreciate any insights on this.

Comment: Why would `last_streak` be 3 for the first row? There was no previous history, so wouldn't you want it to be 0?

Comment: the last_streak counts the number of orders in row from the last order number.

Comment: @DyZ, in that post, consecutive means repeated, not subsequent. This one is a bit different.

Comment: Also, do you expect user a user_id and product_id combination to be repeated later in the `DataFrame`? If so, how do you expect to distinguish that it belongs to a different streak? Just by the index?

Comment: @ALollz No, I don't expect user_id and product_id to be repeated when belong to a different streak. the combination of user_id and product_id must be unique in the result dataframe.

Comment: Then why do you have both a last streak and longest streak? It's unclear what the difference or meaning of these are...

Comment: @ALollz I added one more example above (user_id 3). You can see that the last_streak is 0 as the last order for this user is not a streak order unlike user_id 1 who has 3 consecutive orders for product_id 1. I hope this clarifies things.

Comment: Okay, thanks, those edits make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a loop and `defaultdict`

```
a = defaultdict(lambda:None)
longest = defaultdict(int)
current = defaultdict(int)
for i, j, k in df.itertuples(index=False):
    if a[(i, j)] == k - 1:
        current[(i, j)] += 1 if current[(i, j)] else 2
        longest[(i, j)] = max(longest[(i, j)], current[(i, j)])
    else:
        current[(i, j)] = 0
        longest[(i, j)] |= 0
    a[(i, j)] = k

pd.concat(
    [pd.Series(d) for d in [longest, current]],
    axis=1, keys=['longest_streak', 'last_streak']
).rename_axis(['user_id', 'product_id']).reset_index()

   user_id  product_id  longest_streak  last_streak
0        1           1               3            3
1        1           2               0            0
2        2           1               3            3
3        3           1               2            0
```

Answer (score 1):

I am still not quite sure how you defined the `last_streak`, but, assuming that the same combination of user and product is not repeated, the following calculates the longest streaks:

```
import itertools

def extract_streaks(data):
   streaks = [len(list(rows)) for d,rows in itertools.groupby(data) if d==1.0]
   return max(streaks) + 1 if streaks else 0

df['diffs'] = df.order_number.diff()
df.groupby(['user_id', 'product_id'])['diffs'].apply(extract_streaks)
#user_id  product_id
#1        1             3
#         2             0
#2        1             3
```

---

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
s=df.assign(key=1).set_index(['user_id','product_id','order_number']).key.unstack()  s=s.notnull().astype(int).diff(axis=1).fillna(0).ne(0).cumsum(axis=1).mask(s.isnull())    
s=s.apply(pd.value_counts,1)
s=s.mask(s==1,0)    
pd.concat([s.max(1),s.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:,-1]],1)
Out[974]: 
                    0.0  2.0
user_id product_id          
1       1           3.0  3.0
        2           0.0  0.0
2       1           3.0  3.0
```